# How to convert signs in url/text to hex characters? (converting = to %3D)

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the script I'm making, jquery is getting vars from url parameter. The value that its getting is an url so if its something like

`http://localhost/index.html?url=http://www.example.com/index.php?something=some`

it reads:

```
url = http://www.example.com/index.php?something
```

If its like

`http://localhost/index.html?url=http://www.example.com/index.php?something%3Dsome`

it reads:

`url = http://www.example.com/index.php?something%3Dsome`

which would register as a valid url. my question is how can I search for `=` sign in the `url` variable and replace it with hex `%3D` with jquery or javascript?

Comment: How are you creating this URL? You should escape the whole `url` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the (built-in) `encodeURIComponent()` function:

```
url = 'http://localhost/index.html?url=' +
    encodeURIComponent('http://www.example.com/index.php?something=some');
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)?